# Summing up rows in Pandas without altering the rest of the dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as follows:

```
    Time Sent       Contract        B/S     Price   Qty
9   10:05:46 815    A               BUY     0.55    600
10  10:05:46 815    A               BUY     0.55    153600
11  10:08:47 988    A               SELL    0.56    154200
113 10:20:52 823    B               BUY     0.39    505000
114 14:33:59 424    B               SELL    0.39    505000
31  11:31:44 657    C               BUY     0.92    201000
32  11:36:54 947    C               SELL    0.92    201000
33  11:42:52 228    C               BUY     0.92    166400
34  11:42:52 228    C               BUY     0.92    12900
```

What I hope to achieve here is to sum quantity IF AND ONLY IF all the other columns match up. In this case, the desired output is

```
    Time Sent       Contract        B/S     Price   Qty
9   10:05:46 815    A               BUY     0.55    154200
11  10:08:47 988    A               SELL    0.56    154200
113 10:20:52 823    B               BUY     0.39    505000
114 14:33:59 424    B               SELL    0.39    505000
31  11:31:44 657    C               BUY     0.92    201000
32  11:36:54 947    C               SELL    0.92    201000
33  11:42:52 228    C               BUY     0.92    179300
```

I am perfectly happy with the layout of the data frame, and do not want to use df.groupby() which would mess up the current order. Also note that the first column is the original index position, which I have yet to reset.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['Time Sent', 'Contract', 'B/S', 'Price'], as_index=False)['Qty'].sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create column from `index` first and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `first` for `index` and `sum` for `Qty` column:

```
df = (df.reset_index()
       .groupby(['Time Sent', 'Contract', 'B/S', 'Price'], as_index=False, sort=False)
       .agg({'index':'first', 'Qty':'sum'})
       .set_index('index')
       .rename_axis(None))
print (df)
        Time Sent Contract   B/S  Price     Qty
9    10:05:46 815        A   BUY   0.55  154200
11   10:08:47 988        A  SELL   0.56  154200
113  10:20:52 823        B   BUY   0.39  505000
114  14:33:59 424        B  SELL   0.39  505000
31   11:31:44 657        C   BUY   0.92  201000
32   11:36:54 947        C  SELL   0.92  201000
33   11:42:52 228        C   BUY   0.92  179300
```

If values in index are not necessary and should be reset:

```
df=df.groupby(['Time Sent','Contract','B/S','Price'],as_index=False,sort=False)['Qty'].sum()
print (df)
      Time Sent Contract   B/S  Price     Qty
0  10:05:46 815        A   BUY   0.55  154200
1  10:08:47 988        A  SELL   0.56  154200
2  10:20:52 823        B   BUY   0.39  505000
3  14:33:59 424        B  SELL   0.39  505000
4  11:31:44 657        C   BUY   0.92  201000
5  11:36:54 947        C  SELL   0.92  201000
6  11:42:52 228        C   BUY   0.92  179300
```

Comment: on the nose as always. Thanks!